# CASE Statement in query

Tags: sql, case

I am trying to return a bunch of values in a table without causing "duplicate" outputs. I thought a CASE statement or derived table may help? Any input would be great.

Within the column Product_code there are the following values

(AFF,E,H,PD,PDM,PDRL,PDRM etc)

Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
[Member Id] = c.master_customer_id,
[Full Name] = c.label_name,
[First Name] = c.first_name,
[Last Name] = c.last_name,
[Email] = ISNULL(c.primary_email_address,''),
[Annual Meeting] = MAX(ca.product_code)
CASE WHEN od.product_code IN  (AFF,E,H,PD,PDM,PDRL,PDRM) then ?? 
--[Membership Type] = od.product_code



 FROM order_detail od

 INNER JOIN customer c
 on c.master_customer_id = od.ship_master_customer_id 
    and c.sub_customer_id = od.ship_sub_customer_id 
    and od.subsystem = 'MBR'

INNER JOIN cus_activity ca

    on ca.master_customer_id = c.master_customer_id
    and ca.sub_customer_id = c.sub_customer_id
    and ca.subsystem = 'MTG'
    and ca.activity_subcode IN ('2012AM', '2011AM')
    and ca.product_code IN ('2012AM','2011AM')
INNER JOIN cus_address caddr
    on caddr.master_customer_id = c.master_customer_id
    and caddr.sub_customer_id = c.sub_customer_id
INNER JOIN cus_address_detail caddrd
    on caddrd.cus_address_id = caddr.cus_address_id    

 where c.customer_class_code NOT IN ('STAFF', 'TEST_MBR')
 and c.customer_status_code = 'ACTIVE'
 and c.primary_email_address IS NOT NULL
 and ca.master_customer_id  IN (select order_detail.ship_master_customer_id 
 from order_detail where order_detail.subsystem = 'MBR')    
 and caddrd.priority_seq = 0
 and caddrd.address_status_code = 'GOOD'
 and od.product_code in  
 ( 'AFF','E','H',    'PD','PDM','PDRL','PDRM','PDRU','R',
 'RM','RRL','RRM','RRU','S','SM','SRL','SRM','SRU','SU','SUM','SURL','SURM','SURU' )
 and od.cycle_end_date >= '01/01/2011' and od.cycle_end_date <= '12/31/2012'

 GROUP BY        c.master_customer_id,c.label_name,
 c.FIRST_NAME,c.LAST_NAME,c.primary_email_address,od.product_code,caddr.country_descr

 order by c.master_customer_id
```

Comment: I think you want `od.product_code IN  (AFF,E,H,PD,PDM,PDRL,PDRM)` in a `where` clause.

Comment: apologies... the rest of my query didnt post. Its in there

Comment: where c.customer_class_code NOT IN ('STAFF', 'TEST_MBR')
and c.customer_status_code = 'ACTIVE'
and c.primary_email_address IS NOT NULL
and ca.master_customer_id  IN (select order_detail.ship_master_customer_id from order_detail where order_detail.subsystem = 'MBR') 
and caddrd.priority_seq = 0
and caddrd.address_status_code = 'GOOD'
and od.product_code in  ( 'AFF','E','H', 'PD','PDM','PDRL','PDRM','PDRU','R','RM','RRL','RRM','RRU','S','SM','SRL','SRM','SRU','SU','SUM','SURL','SURM','SURU' )

Comment: @ShawnRahmani - there's an *edit* link at the bottom of your question. Please *edit* your question to include the rest of your code - as you may have noticed, there's no decent code formatting in the comments, so what you've posted is unreadable.

Comment: ok i added the rest of the query

Comment: let me ask this... you DONT want "duplicate outputs".  Is this in reference to multiple records for same master customer ID, but you want to know if they have any of the given "product codes", and if so which ones along the same returned row for each respective customer?

Comment: That is correct @DRapp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a Cross-Tab result (also known as a Pivot table) based on a given customer.  You want all possible membership status levels as a person could be multiple levels (per your example).

With the group by on the customer ID, everything will roll-up to the member.  So, if there are multiple product codes, I have applied SUM() based on each individual "product_code" you wanted to consider.

Next, to help optimize your query, I would ensure your Order_Detail has an index on
( SubSystem, Product_Code, Cycle_End_Date, ship_master_customer_id )

I've slightly rewritten to better allow myself to follow what you were getting and the criteria related to each table.  Hopefully it makes sense to what you started with.

```
SELECT 
      c.master_customer_id as [Member Id],
      c.label_name as [Full Name],
      c.first_name as [First Name],
      c.last_name as [Last Name],
      ISNULL(c.primary_email_address,'') as [Email],
      MAX(ca.product_code) as [Annual Meeting],
      SUM( CASE WHEN od.product_code = 'AFF' then 1 else 0 end ) as Membership_AFF,
      SUM( CASE WHEN od.product_code = 'E' then 1 else 0 end ) as Membership_E,
      SUM( CASE WHEN od.product_code = 'H' then 1 else 0 end ) as Membership_H,
      SUM( CASE WHEN od.product_code = 'PD' then 1 else 0 end ) as Membership_PD,
      SUM( CASE WHEN od.product_code = 'PDM' then 1 else 0 end ) as Membership_PDM,
      SUM( CASE WHEN od.product_code = 'PDRL' then 1 else 0 end ) as Membership_PDRL,
      SUM( CASE WHEN od.product_code = 'PDRM' then 1 else 0 end ) as Membership_PDRM
   FROM 
      order_detail od
         INNER JOIN customer c
            on od.ship_master_customer_id = c.master_customer_id
           and od.ship_sub_customer_id = c.sub_customer_id
           and c.customer_class_code NOT IN ('STAFF', 'TEST_MBR')
           and c.customer_status_code = 'ACTIVE'
           and c.primary_email_address IS NOT NULL

        INNER JOIN cus_activity ca
           on od.ship_master_customer_id = ca.master_customer_id
          and od.ship_sub_customer_id = ca.sub_customer_id
          and ca.subsystem = 'MTG'
          and ca.activity_subcode IN ('2012AM', '2011AM')
          and ca.product_code IN ('2012AM','2011AM')

        INNER JOIN cus_address caddr
           on od.ship_master_customer_id = caddr.master_customer_id
          and od.ship_sub_customer_id = caddr.sub_customer_id

           INNER JOIN cus_address_detail caddrd
              on caddr.cus_address_id = caddrd.cus_address_id
             and caddrd.priority_seq = 0
             and caddrd.address_status_code = 'GOOD'

   WHERE
          od.subsystem = 'MBR'
      and od.product_code in ( 'AFF','E','H','PD','PDM','PDRL','PDRM','PDRU',
                               'R','RM','RRL','RRM','RRU','S','SM','SRL',
                               'SRM','SRU','SU','SUM','SURL','SURM','SURU' )
      and od.cycle_end_date >= '01/01/2011' 
      and od.cycle_end_date <= '12/31/2012'

   GROUP BY        
      od.ship_master_customer_id,
      c.label_name,
      c.FIRST_NAME,
      c.LAST_NAME,
      c.primary_email_address,
      caddr.country_descr

   order by
      od.ship_master_customer_id
```

Comment: If that worked, great... and as a newbie to the site, help others by up-checking answers that help... and those that SOLVED your question, click the checkmark next to the answer so others know it has been solved and don't keep trying to post answers.